# Ambiguous Countdown Conundrums?

Tags: production, countdown

[**Countdown**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countdown_(game_show)) is a very long-running game show in the UK.

I was watching a comedy-take on the show, [**8 Out of 10 Cats Does Countdown**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8_Out_of_10_Cats_Does_Countdown) and the (non-crucial) conundrum was:

> `T W A R T E H A B`

The scientist in me unscrambled this to:

> `W A T E R B A T H`

However on the show one of the contestants correctly gave the answer as:

> `B A T H W A T E R`

(facepalm)

**Have there ever been any ambiguous Countdown Conundrums (on the original show) and have they ever affected the outcome of the game?**

By ambiguous I mean that the 9-letter conundrum can be unscrambled into (at least) two different words?

Comment: Is there any implication on the show that one of the two answers would be counted as "wrong" if it were suggested? If both answers are valid, I don't see how it would affect the game's outcome.

Comment: Well the 'reveal' of the answer is rather old-school, and a pre-arranged set of letters is spun into view, so the 'correct' answer must be set before the conundrum begins. [**For instance**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-n9aILIF_ms)

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I don't know that I've seen the game, so I wasn't aware of that game mechanic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a rule, they try not to have ambiguous Conundrum solutions to avoid confusion. However, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countdown_%28game_show%29#Conundrum):

> Each conundrum is designed to have only one solution but if, unintentionally, the conundrum has **two answers** (e.g. CARTHORSE and ORCHESTRA) then **either is accepted.**

As for an example of this happening, there's episode 1332 from Jan 1993, in which the production came up with an interesting workaround. From the [Countdown Wikia](http://wiki.apterous.org/Episode_1332):

> According to [contestant and series 22 champion] Waddington, the conundrum round was originally set with the answer as **RELAPSING**, to which he 'incorrectly' buzzed with the answer **SPANGLIER**. It was then discovered that the word was indeed valid, and so **a retake was shot** with the original intended answer as the scramble. *[You can see the relevant scene [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJ68w1XnJAk#t=1m30s).]*

There are also cases where the 2nd solution is displayed *upfront*, probably to throw contestants off. Here's one instance of it where a contestant indeed fell for it, answering GERANIUMS, the word that is already displayed (which is plural and isn't allowed) instead of MEASURING [the relevant bit is at 6:47]: